# Sound poor on Dell 7390 laptop

Tags: sound

I have a dell 7390 laptop on which I have sky go and BT sport apps, the sound at 100% is audible but only just. how can I increase the volume further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pavucontrol` or `pulsemixer` to increase the volume up to 150% and `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ <volume>%` to set it to whatever you want